# $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [c,d]$ be monotone and bijective. If $b-a>d-c$ can we say that function is decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [c,d]$ be monotone and bijective. If $b-a>d-c$ can we say that function is decreasing.

Is this true?

Thanks.

Comment: Surely not. $f:[0, 2] \to [0, 1]$, $f(x) = x/2$ is increasing.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No. In general, consider the function $$f(x)=c+\Big(\frac{d-c}{b-a}\Big)(x-a)$$
even if $(b-a)>(d-c)$, the $f(x)$ is increasing. You can try to prove that it is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true.
Consider:

$f: [0,1]\to [0,\tfrac12]$, $x\mapsto \tfrac12x$

$f$ is obviously monotone and bijective and it is $b-a=1>d-c=\tfrac12$. 
But $f$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Any monotone increasing function can be turned into a monotone decreasing function just by flipping its graph upside down.

Formally, suppose that $g$ is any bijective monotone increasing function $g:[a,b]\to[c,d]$. Then 
$$f(x) = d+c-g(x)$$
is easily shown to be bijective and monotone decreasing.

(Similarly, one can flip the graph horizontally instead of vertically, obtaining the monotone decreasing function $f'(x) = g(a+b-x)$.)

So if there are *any* monotone bijective functions, there must be decreasing ones.